# Create Biztalk 2013 artifact for sharepoint in visual studio

Tags: sharepoint, biztalk

To create artifacts(schemas and ports) from WCF, webservice or database to be used in visual studio project, I right click the project and I choose Add Generated Items under the add menu and the related adapter generates them.

I have a case where I need to integrate data from sharepoint 2010 in my project. is there a way to generate these artifacts for a sharepoint list in my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you don't need to generate any schemas for SharePoint.
To populate a list for example you would need to fill in the properties of the SharePoint adapter by promoting an XML file as a property.

You can find more information here: http://jpsmit.bloggingabout.net/2013/01/24/biztalk-server-2013-sharepoint-adapter-walkthrough/